# STS - Not able to run application

Tags: java, grails, spring-tool-suite

I have multiple projects in my project explorer so just now I started working on a application but I don't all other application got corrupted.

I don't know reason.

I know that I can import project from workspace, but looking for different way cause it happening many times with me.

How can I recover all application? please refer image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they're still in your workspace maybe they're just **closed**? Try to click each project right mouse button and choose '*Open project*'.